# Clarifying "400 - Bad Request"

Tags: javascript, html, express, http-status-code-400

I am triggering a bad request on purpose from my backend. The backend using express is answering properly as expected with:

```
[...]

.catch((error) => {
  res.statusCode = 400;
  res.json({
    msg: "This is some error",
    err: error,
  });
});
```

My question is: Is the 400 always showing up in browser console? I thought I handled the error the right way.
[image]

And why do I have to retrieve the data in the frontend with

```
// 400: 
function (data) {
  var data = data.responseJSON.msg);
}
```

instead of (similar to 200:)

```
// 400: 
function (data) {
  var data = data.msg);
}
```

I am just wondering, if I do something wrong.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: I tried to interpret what you meant and I edited the question. Feel free to revert the edit in case it was wrong :)

Comment: 4xx and 5xx denotes some kind of error and will be logged in browser console regardless of error handlers

Comment: Regarding the handling of 400 and 200 can show the express code how you are sending response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When fetching data asynchronously, any response other than a `2**` response code gets handled by a `.catch` block. So any other response whether it be `4**` or `5**` gets caught by the catch block and for that reason if you're using a library like Axios or the likes the response from the backend will be in the `error.response`  or `data.response` in your case.

I wasn't aware of what you're using to carry out the asynchronous fetching of data i.e. Fetch Api so my answer is a generic response and also is the above code complete?

In my experience any error from whatever weither it be am asynchronous call that generates an error always gets logged to the console, but you can from the front end handle those errors in the catch block

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when the `console.log` tries to output the error, the string representation is printed, not the object structure, so you do not see the `.response` property or in your case the `.responseJSON`

By catching your error with an catch block `.catch()` or if you using `async / await` you should, usually, wrap the code inside of an `try / catch` to catch the error otherwise it will always output this red error in the console